# Is it possible to query firebase-firestore data by multiple criteria/values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to query firestore with optional multiple criteria?
Let's say I want to filter the data from firebase firestore collection if the user provides optional input from multiple input fields (example: Job Type, Salary range, location, date posted, etc... )

Comment: For sure you can. Have you tried something?

Answer (score 0):

To build a query out of multiple conditions:

```
let query = firebase.firestore().collection("your collection");
if (jobType) {
  query = query.where("jobType", "==", jobType);
}
if (salaryRangeMin && salaryRangeMax) {
  query = query.where("salary", ">=", salaryRangeMin)
               .where("salary", "<=", salaryRangeax);
}
if (location) {
  query = query.where("location", "==", location);
}
const snapshot = await query.get();
```